# Android Search View to remove cross icon

Tags: android

I am using the search view in custom Toolbar according to my design, I am having another cross icon, so I want to remove the cross icon for search view them on default provided by android.

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_learning_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:queryHint="@string/toolBar_hint"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:searchIcon="@null"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/element_padding_small"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/element_padding_small"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:queryBackground="@color/White"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</SearchView>

ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
                        searchViewIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(CustomSearchActivity.this, ""+searchViewIcon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to do so-

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            searchViewIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
   });
```

Comment: Sorry... to say it not working i am getting null pointer exception when i am trying to enter some text into it